# Is it call to rollback transaction when I return and exit from using block without complete the transactionscope?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

Using (In EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 6.0.6)

```cs
using (TransactionScope scope = new(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{

    // doing some operations and if invalide operations found
    return new ReultObject(0, "error message");
        
    // Else doing some operatio`enter code here`ns and complete TransactionScope
    scope.Complete();
}
```